# Sum up columns depending on same values in other column

Tags: excel-2013

I want to sum up each entries of column 2 corresponding to the date in column 1 so that I can insert the formula into the first cell in column 3 and drag&drop it to the end of the column.

Tried:
=XLOOKUP(A52;A52:B63;2) and some macros but without macro experience

Expecting:
[Excel Screenshot. Column 3 expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otZ1H.png)

Comment: The sum of 2022-10-07 is an error or its what you expect? If it's expected, can you explain the logic?

Comment: Exactly. the column with the sum is my expectation. I want to sum up all the values for each date.

Comment: You didn't understand. The third column does not correspond to the sum of the values from 2022-10-07. Is it expected?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a macro. Its need only a `IF` (to hide the value when it's not the final date's row) and a `SUMIF` (to sum conditionally if the date is the same as the current row's one).

Considering your columns are A, B and C, it's just to put the following formula in C1 and drag it to the end:

```
=IF(A1<>A2;SUMIF(A:A;A1;B:B);"")
```

If your columns aren't A, B and C, just change the respective ones.

**EXPLANATION:** It's pretty straightforward, but there are two parts.

`SUMIF(A:A;A1;B:B)` sums all values in column B whenever the date in column A is the same as the date in A1 ([documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)).

`IF(A1<>A2;SUMIF(etc);"")` shows the sum only when the date in the current row is different from the next one ([documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)).

In your example, the result for 2022-10-07 is not the sum; I'll take it as a mistake from your example. If it's an intended effect (with some logic other than a simple sum), explain it in comments.